# Does select_related on an already queryed field perform a SQL query?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-orm

Let's assume that Car has multiple wheels and a wheel has one color.
Does the 4th line performs an SQL query ?

```
cars = Car.objects.prefetch_related('wheel_set__color')
for car in cars:
    for wheel in car.wheel_set:
        print(wheel.color)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks about select_related() but your code specifies prefetch_related() so I'll address both.

The following will hit the database once:

```
cars = Car.objects.select_related('wheel_set__color')
for car in cars:
    for wheel in car.wheel_set:
        print(wheel.color)
```

The following will hit the database three times:

```
cars = Car.objects.prefetch_related('wheel_set__color')
for car in cars:
    for wheel in car.wheel_set:
        print(wheel.color)
```

However, the following will hit the database twice:

```
cars = Car.objects.select_related('wheel_set').prefetch_related('wheel_set__color')
for car in cars:
    for wheel in car.wheel_set:
        print(wheel.color)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: Thank you for pointing out to me the absence of select related, I actually forgot a line :

    `cars = Car.objects.prefetch_related('wheel_set__color')
    for car in cars:
        car.select_related('wheel_set')
        for wheel in car.wheel_set:
            print(wheel.color)`

Comment: I don't see why you would do that. Is your intent to minimize the number of database queries?